# ElementListSelectionDialog has no elements

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, swt, jface

I'm trying to use a [ElementListSelectionDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/ElementListSelectionDialog.html). I've followed the example code but for whatever reason the dialog show but with no options

My Code:

```
ElementListSelectionDialog dialog = 
      new ElementListSelectionDialog(shlSpriteCreator, new LabelProvider());
dialog.setMultipleSelection(false);
dialog.setIgnoreCase(true);
dialog.setAllowDuplicates(true);
dialog.setMessage("Select an AI");
dialog.setTitle("What AI to use?");
dialog.setElements(new String[]{"HELLO","GOODBYE"});
if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {
    aiControllerLocation = (String) dialog.getFirstResult();
}
```

The resulting dialog:

[image: Dialog with no options to select]

I originally used an array of classes but since it would not work I substituted for a list of trivial strings although as I understand it by using the [LabelProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/LabelProvider.html) class I should be able to use any object and it will be displayed by it's toString() representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of dialog works normally under Workbench UI. To run this dialog correctly you should use the sample code

```
ElementListSelectionDialog dialog = 
    new ElementListSelectionDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell(), new LabelProvider());
```

Comment: Oh I see the source of my problem. I followed an erroneous blog post about jface dialogs. Reconsulting the documentation I noticed that while inherited from a jface dialog ElementListSelectionDialog is in the org.eclipse.ui.dialogs package. I guess I'll have to write my own.