# How to create a dialog with checkboxes that allows multiple selections

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

Having read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126311/elementlistselectiondialog-has-no-elements/25428335), I want to create a dialog where I can select multiple items which to be in the form of check boxes.
`ElementListSelectionDialog` doesn't show any elements in the dialog.

```
final ElementListSelectionDialog dialog = new     ElementListSelectionDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell(), new LabelProvider());
dialog.setElements(new String[] { "1", "2", "3" });
dialog.setTitle("Numbers");
dialog.setMultipleSelection(true);
dialog.setInitialSelections(new String[] { "1", "2", "3" });
dialog.open();
```

Using the code above, I get the items in the dialog sometimes, but there are two problems:

1. I only get them sometimes
2. It is not in the form of checkboxes.

If you know a better way of doing this, please let me know.
I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do you need the filter functionality?

Comment: Note: `ElementListSelectionDialog` is an Eclipse UI dialog, not SWT or JFace. This is OK if you are doing a plugin but not OK for a standalone SWT/JFace app.

Comment: @Baz, no I don't need the filter functionality.

Comment: @greg-449, I want to open up this dialog in RCP application, as an action in a right click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ElementListSelectionDialog` does not support check box selection.

You may be able to use `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ListSelectionDialog`:

```
String [] elements = ...

ListSelectionDialog dialog = 
   new ListSelectionDialog(shell, elements, ArrayContentProvider.getInstance(),
            new LabelProvider(), "selection message");

dialog.setTitle("dialog title");

dialog.setInitialSelections(new Object []{....selections});

dialog.open();

Object [] result = dialog.getResult();
```

or you can always write your own dialog using `CheckboxTableViewer`.